# Ruby On Rails - Not able to assign attributes to new object with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm fairly new to rails, having a problem creating a new object with associations.  I have 3 objects: User, Job, Bid.  A bid belongs to user and belongs to job.  A job and a user each has many bids.  My problem is that when I try to create a new bid using the bid hash in params, none of bids attributes are updated.

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :job
belongs_to :user

attr_accessor :pay_type, :rate, :comment
attr_protected :user_id, :job_id

end
```

in the bids controller create action, params[:bid] yields this: 
    {"pay_type"=>"HOURLY", "rate"=>"88", "comment"=>"bid test"}

but if i try

```
@bid = Bid.new(params[:bid])
```

@bid =

```
<Bid id: nil, pay_type: nil, rate: nil, comment: nil, user_id: nil, job_id: nil>
```

I've also tried

```
@job.bids.build(params[:bid])
```

but the only bid attribute that gets assigned is job_id:

```
<Bid id: nil, pay_type: nil, rate: nil, comment: nil, user_id: nil, job_id: 4>
```

Any direction would be much appreciated.  Let me know if I should provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I think you want to use `attr_accessible` instead of `attr_accessor`, since what you're trying to do is set those parameters via mass-assignment.

Check out the [attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) documentation for details on how this works. Also, keep in mind that you'll want to ensure your app is secure from the mass-assignment vulnerabilities - just follow the docs carefully and you should be okay.